# Apache Commons Logging - How to move configuration file to outside the Jar?

Tags: java, apache-commons-logging

I have a Java application that uses Apache Commons Logging. Currently the config file for this is in `src/main/resources/`. It runs and logs as I would like. The problem is that this config file gets compiled into the jar file. When it is deployed, this will be an issue. I need to be able to change logging levels etc once deployed. I understand Apache Commons Logging is a "higher level" implementation that actually uses another implementation underneath, in this case it is log4j.

I have tried the following to specify a directory named config which will be at the same level as the jar file:

```
static {
   System.setProperty("log4j.configuration","./config/log4j.properties");
}
private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

I have also tried:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file://./config/log4j.properties
```

I have tried several variations of the -D, some with file, some without.

How do I move the configuration file to outside the Jar?

Comment: Check whether you use `log4j` or `log4j2` as logging api. Depending on that your properties and configuration files may be named differently. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to John Williams for his direction- it was very helpful in getting me on the right track.  It did not fully work.  What I ended up doing was the following:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration="file:/C:/Path/config/log4j.properties"
```

Simple- I know- but I was missing the file: in my path.

Comment: I think you should accept this answer - it's helpful. I have deleted my answer.